# RegEx: Grabbing values from parameters

Tags: php, regex

How can I grab only the value from the 'field' parameter between single or double quotes?
String: `{{code field='mail' type='news'}}` or `{{code field="mail" type='news'}}`

I tried this pattern: `(?:^|&)b=([^&]*)`

But it doesn't stop at the second quotation mark and gives me `'mail' type='news'` as a result, I need it to only return `mail`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `field=['"](.+?)['"]` is what you are looking for.

See it working on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/1TWrXO/1).